# Writing python plugin: How terminate plugin from script without closing QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm writing a QGIS conversion plugin in python to be able to create Obstacle-files for a model from shapefiles.

What I want to do now is just to close the plugin cleanly. This means, to close the GUI, to delete the variables and so on. I tried to use sys.exit(), but it also closes QGIS.

How do I only close the plugin?

Comment: Consider using an object-oriented approach while coding your plugin. If you create your dialog and your (nested) functions as object, you can just delete (`del`) the whole object after computations finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a subclass of QWidget (e.g. a QDialog or QMainWindow) you can simply call the widget's *close* or *hide* method. If you want to free memory used by your variables you can delete them with *del* or set them to *None* and they will be garbage collected.

Comment: Hm, this does to close the GUI. Thanks for that! But for the variables, there has to be an easier way. I have some dozens of variables, that are created or not depending on different conditions. I would have to check for any of them if it was created and delete it or not...?